# How to validate id_token acquired by msal-react in .Net api

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I am using **@azure/msal-react(v2)** and **@azure/msal-browser(v3)** libraries in **react** **SPA** app.
I acquire id_token and access_token in my react app. Then, I pass this id_token to my back-end and would like to validate it.
Is there a way that I can call Microsoft api to pass this token (along with client_Id and cleint_secret) and it gives me response like user info. So I make sure that this token is valid?

Comment: What is the technical limitation to using PKCE and can you resolve that instead? 
The implicit flow is an inferior flow, allowing several attack vectors and hence will not be included in the [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/) specification.

Comment: I am Ok with PKCE. But, since the id_token is visible in the browser and based on that, I generate my access_token in the back-end, a middle-man can break the id_token and call my api to generate an access_token and access to the users in my db.

Comment: An id_token should not be sent to your API. If you're using HTTPS, the id_token and access_token will only be available to the device and a middle-man would not be able to inspect the response from the /token endpoint. If the user (therefore browser) is in possession of the access token, you should allow them to use it on your APIs - and your API should 100% validate this. The access token signature is validated against public keys for your tenant to ensure it has not been tampered with.

Comment: I would like to implement Code Flow. What is the solution to get the code in the SPA and pass it to the back-end, then exchange it with id_token in the back-end?